# Bidirectional Arrow

Tags: haskell, arrows

I'm trying to capture a symmetrical data processing pipeline using arrows, and was wondering if bidirectional composition is possible.

Control.Arrow exposes the following

```
-- | Left to right composition
(>>>) :: Category cat => cat a b -> cat b c -> cat a c 

-- | Right to left composition
(<<<) :: Category cat => cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

what I'd like, but cannot work out how to express is **bidirectional composition of pairs**. The type is something like.

```
(<^>) :: Category cat => cat (a,y) (b,z) -> cat (b,x) (c,y) -> cat (a,x) (c,z)
```

where the first element of each pair is to composed left-to-right, and the second to be composed right-to-left.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, at least not without some audacious infinite knot tying or unsafe use of bottom values. It could very well be done under some extra constraints though – what's your actual use case?

Comment: I've a configurable set of encoding / decoding operators, each of which has type (a,b) -> (a', b'). I can tie them together manually, but pipes seemed a good fit. It would be perfect, except the encoding pipeline needs to be composed left to light, and the decode right to left.

Comment: Why not just split the tuples and then compose?

Comment: Well yes: that's what I've implemented for the time being. I was just wondering if it could be done more elegantly. Its got to be a common pattern. Many (most?) encoding pipelines tend to come with an inverse, and composing a list of bi directional operations with a fold is very elegant.

Comment: @OllieB No idea if this helps with your problem, but have you seen [Control.Invertible.BiArrow](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invertible-0.2.0/docs/Control-Invertible-BiArrow.html)?

Comment: Maybe your are looking for something like `Product (->) (Op (->))`, exploiting `Data.Category`?

Comment: I'll have to study these in more detail.

Comment: BiArrows definitely capture the spirit of what I intended. Its not quite the same idea, and I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anything else turns up

Comment: @chi I'm afraid I don't grok your comment. Could you elaborate? (I don't have a higher education in category theory _or_ computer science).

Comment: Basically, `Op (->)` is flipped `(->)`, i.e. `Op (->) a b` is actually `b -> a` (function going "backward"). Then the category `Product (->) (Op (->))` composes a morphism in `(->)` (forward function) and one in `Op (->)` (backward function). Hence, `>>>` in this category should work as you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'll explore that more tomorrow.

Comment: @OllieB My notation was a bit off in my comments above. My answer below should have the correct notation -- at least I tested it :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of a category involving pairs of forward and backwards functions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, GADTs #-}

import Prelude hiding ((.))
import Data.Category
import Data.Category.Product

type C = (->) :**: (Op (->))
```

The above states that `C (a,b) (c,d)` is isomorphic to a pair `(a->c, d->b)`. Pairs "compose" in the category in the natural way: the forward functions are composed forwards, the backwards functions are composed backwards.

Here are two examples:

```
f :: C (String, Bool) (Int, Char)
f = length :**: Op (=='a')
```

Note how the backwards function has to be wrapped in an `Op` (belongs to the "opposite" category).

```
g :: C (Int, Char) ([Int], Maybe Char)
g = (\x->[x,x]) :**: Op (maybe 'X' id)
```

Note how the "source" of `g` is the "target" of `f`. This ensures composition is possible.

```
composed :: C (String, Bool) ([Int], Maybe Char)
composed = g . f

test :: ([Int], Bool)
test = case composed of
   (forward :**: Op backward) -> (forward "abcde", backward Nothing)
-- result: ([5,5],False)
```

On a more practical side, note that `Data.Category` and `Control.Category` are different beasts :-( and that the `Control.Arrow` library mentioned in the question uses the latter.

Still, it should be possible to define `Op` and `:**:` for `Control.Category` as well. Maybe it's already on hackage somewhere (?).

Answer (score 2):

Some further approaches, best recorded as a separate answer.

The first imposes the additional constraint of an `ArrowLoop`, and is defined using a recursive arrow `do` notation.

From a data flow viewpoint however, no recursion is taking place.

```hs
(<->) ∷ (ArrowLoop a) ⇒ a (b,f) (c,g) → a (c,e) (d,f) → a (b,e) (d,g)
(<->) f1 f2 = proc (b, e) → do
  rec
    (c,g) ← f1 ↢ (b,f)
    (d,f) ← f2 ↢ (c,e)
  returnA ↢ (d,g)
```

It could equally be defined as

```hs
(<->) ∷ (ArrowLoop a) ⇒ a (b,f) (c,g) → a (c,e) (d,f) → a (b,e) (d,g)
(<->) f1 f2 = proc (b, e) → do
  rec
    (d,f) ← f2 ↢ (c,e)
    (c,g) ← f1 ↢ (b,f)
  returnA ↢ (d,g)
```

The second approach does not: I've yet to work out if this is a sane thing to do.

```hs
(<->) ∷ (Arrow a) ⇒ a (b,f) (c,g) → a (c,e) (d,f) → a (b,e) (d,g)
(<->) f1 f2 = proc (b, e) → do
  (c,_) ← f1 ↢ (b,undefined)
  (d,_) ← f2 ↢ (c,undefined)
  (_,f) ← f2 ↢ (undefined,e)
  (_,g) ← f1 ↢ (undefined,f)
  returnA ↢ (d,g)
```

The following is the same as the second approach, but defined explicitly in terms of composition functions.

```
(<->) ∷ (Arrow a) ⇒ a (b,f) (c,g) → a (c,e) (d,f) → a (b,e) (d,g)
(<->) f g =
  let toFst x = (x,undefined)
      toSnd x = (undefined,x)
  in
    (arr toFst ⋙ f ⋙ arr fst ⋙ arr toFst ⋙ g ⋙ arr fst) ⁂
    (arr snd ⋘ f ⋘ arr toSnd ⋘ arr snd ⋘ g ⋘ arr toSnd)
```